# How to use Laravel 5.1 schedule?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-5.1, cron-task

I'm trying to use laravel 5.1 [scheduler](http://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling#defining-schedules) to run a data grabbing commands from twitter and store it in the database. If I put the actual command within the Kernel.php file it runs no worries and gets/inserts the data into the database but when I try put it into an external file to run and just put the command in the Kernel I get this

```
Running scheduled command: (touch/storage/framework/schedule-4ff51352255727a7381f73c7bd3eb90c; '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.18/bin/php' 'artisan' lookup; rm /storage/framework/schedule-4ff51352255727a7381f73c7bd3eb90c) > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

This is my Kernal.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use DB;
use Session;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Thujohn\Twitter\Facades\Twitter;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class,
    \App\Console\Commands\Scheduled_post::class,
];

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('lookup')
             ->everyMinute()
             ->withoutOverlapping();
}
}
```

and my command

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring;

class Lookup extends Command
{
/**
 * The name and signature of the console command.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $signature = 'Lookup';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Performing user lookup';

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle()
{
    $user_lookup = Twitter::getUsersLookup(['screen_name' => 'some_user', 'format' => 'object']);
        $social_user = array(
            'email'                     => null,
            'screen_name'               => $user_lookup[0]->screen_name,
        );
        DB::table('social_users')->insert( $social_user );
}
}
```

Testing in MAMP, manually executing `php artisan schedule:run` through terminal to test.

Im not sure how to fix this or whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, in your Kernel, use the correct signature, and add the command to your :

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use DB;
use Session;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Thujohn\Twitter\Facades\Twitter;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class,
    \App\Console\Commands\Scheduled_post::class,
    \App\Console\Commands\Lookup::class,
];

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('Lookup')
             ->everyMinute()
             ->withoutOverlapping();
}
}
It
```

It's Lookup not lookup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem, database still remains empty but if I run it within the kernel file itself the function runs perfectly.

Comment: what happens when you run 'php artisan Lookup'

Comment: Get this error `[InvalidArgumentException] Command "Lookup" is not defined.`

Comment: I have edited the answer, you are missing the command definition, in the commands array

Comment: That fixed it. You're a big help, I completely missed that. Thanks alot!